# pragma pack(push) on iphone

Tags: c++, iphone, pragma, pragma-pack

I have a structure within `#pragma pack(push,1)` and `#pragma pack(pop)`. I would like to know if this will properly work on iphone compiler, and if there might be other side effects outside of those macros.

Thanks,
Raxvan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#pragma pack(push)` and `#pragma pack(pop)` statements should work like you are used to in let's say `C++`, and they should have no side-effects.
`GCC` and `LLVM` will compile this like they would do normally using any other C-like language.